# An error occurred while installing rack (2.0.1), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install rack -v '2.0.1'` succeeds before bundling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What do I do about this?

"An error occurred while installing rack (2.0.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rack -v '2.0.1'` succeeds before bundling."

Answer (score 0):

Rack 2.0.1 requires Ruby >= 2.2.2.

Whats ur ruby version ?? check using `ruby -v` in the command line

Comment: ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883)